# Переопределение конструктора Array

Tags: c#, массивы, наследование, конструктор

Суть: создаю массив объектов пользовательского класса. И очень хотелось бы, чтобы каждый элемент знал свой номер. Именно относительно конкретного массива. Понятно, что при инициализации массива используется базовый конструктор аррея. Но вот как его переопределить для решения задачи? Ведь сам Array не наследуется.

Comment: только вручную обновлять индекс при сохранении объекта в массив

Comment: скорее всего тебе не нужен массив, а нужна своя собственная коллекция, а уже в ней можно делать что угодно

Comment: Э, а каким образом элемент узнает свой индекс? Для этого в элементе этот самый индекс нужно где-то хранить. Расскажите лучше, для чего это вам, какую проблему вы хотите таким образом решить.

Comment: используйте список, тот же массив по сути, только куда с более широкими возможностями

Comment: @VladD создаю массив с автосортировкой элементов при изменении какого-либо из них

Comment: @Garrus_En а лист предоставляет такую возможность?

Comment: @wemon: А как элемент массива узнает, что его поменяли? И что делать, если этот элемент лежит одновременно в нескольких массивах? Он должен знать все свои индексы?

Comment: @VladD да, всё это проблемы, но я с ними уже разобрался. Немного костыляво, но всё же. Выглядит это так: в структуре элементов храню статичную ссылку на массив. Когда происходит обращение к самому массиву (а только так мы можем получить доступ к элементу), происходит передача ссылки в структуру. Да, остаётся проблема общности ячеек. Ну здесь как вариант просто запретить обмен ссылками в свойстве, заменив его на клонирование. Ну... возможно есть и менее кривые способы, но я о них пока особо не думал). Основной проблемой остаётся установление номера. Пока что решаю это статическим счётчиком

Comment: @VladD Но тогда невозможным становится одновременное хранение двух массивов. Ибо счётчик должен обнуляться при вызове конструктора. Для этого нужно его переопределить... но вот как? Заменить конструктор делегатом, связывающим конструктор массива, конструктор структуры и занулятор счётчика? Ну как-то совсем косо смотрится